# Returning value from function (setting variable from existing variable name)

Tags: function, powershell

I would like to pass two arguments to my function and set a variable (and variable name) based on the results. I've been trying to do this the following way:

```
$service_to_check_for = "ping"

function check-service-monitored ($check_command,$check_name) {
    if($service_to_check_for -eq $check_command)
    {
        $Value = "Yes"
    }
    else
    {
        $Value = "No"
    }       

    $script:check_command = $check_command
    $script:check_name = $check_name
    $script:value = $Value
}

check-service-monitored "ping" "NagiosPing"

echo "$check_name : $value"
```

I would like

```
     $NagiosPing = "Yes"
```

but how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make sure that the only value your function prints out is the result:

```
$service_to_check_for = "ping"

function check-service-monitored ($check_command,$check_name) {
if($service_to_check_for -eq $check_command)
{
    "Yes"
}
else
{
    "No"
}       

$script:check_command = $check_command
$script:check_name = $check_name
$script:value = $Value
}

$NagiosPing = check-service-monitored "ping" "NagiosPing"
$NagiosPing
```

The only output your function provides now is Yes or No, just assign it to your variable

Comment: Thank you so much!! I didn't think of setting the function as a variable!
This is my finished code:

 $service_to_check_for = "ping"

 function check-service-monitored ($check_command) {
  if($service_to_check_for -eq $check_command)
  {
   $Value = "Yes"
  }
  else
  {
   $Value = "No"
  }  
  return $value
 }
   
 $nagiosping = check-service-monitored "ping"

 echo "Monitor: $nagiosping"

Comment: Of course! For some reason I was unable to (you can accept this answer momentarily). Again, thank you!!